# Create a file for a different user

Tags: python, file-io, chown

I would like to create a file (preferably using with `open(…)`) and have the owner be a different person than the person running the code.

I have tried to create the file and use `os.chown` to change the owner, but that doesn't seem to work. Here is what I tried:

```
import os
import pwd
user=pwd.getpwnam('user')
with open('somefile', 'w') as f:
    f.write('blah, blah')

os.chown('somefile', user.pw_uid, user.pw_gid)
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'somefile'
```

I would have thought that that was the correct way to change the owner of a file.

Comment: Your code is fine but an ordinary user dos not have permission to do this.  (This is a purposeful restriction by the operating system you cannot code around.)  You'll have to run your program as a user with appropriate privileges.  Note, however, that there is a race condition in the time window where the file is already created but not `chown()`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are not creating the new file as root, which is required. check out the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636136/how-to-execute-os-methods-as-root) question in SO. should solve the problem.

UPDATE:
you need super user privileges to do this. so when running your program, use

```
sudo python yourprogramname.py
```

this will allow your python script super user privileges.

Comment: os.getenv('SUDO_UID') returns None for me.

Comment: are you running as super user? start python with `sudo python` command. it will ask for your password. then after you enter your password it will open python like normal. only this time it should return an id, like '1002' or something similar.