# Change to root user in python

Tags: python

How can i change to root user providing my password in the script?

I have this code

```
import os

# change to root user

# changing to root call this function
# example
os.sytem('reboot')
```

PS. not only this function but iptables too, so i need to change to root with out typing the password because i want to be automated.

Comment: use `visudo`: try it before. [Link](https://askubuntu.com/a/168885/772449)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute os.\* methods as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636136/how-to-execute-os-methods-as-root)

Comment: You should also avoid storing login credential (username, password) in your code.
If you're curious why take a look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/150601)

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191878/change-to-sudo-user-within-a-python-script Use some part of the program for root user as a sub-process.i.e Use subprocess import instead of using os.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do anything after the call to `reboot`, you can use `os.exec*()` to replace the current Python process with `sudo`, which will switch to the root user. Then, have `sudo` execute `reboot` as below.

```
import os
import shutil


SUDO_PATH = shutil.which('sudo')

if SUDO_PATH is None:
    raise OSError('cannot find sudo executable')

os.execl(SUDO_PATH, SUDO_PATH, 'reboot')
```

For the cases where you wish do something after executing an external process, use `subprocess.run()`.