# PermissionError: exception when running an os.chmod() with sudo. Python3 3

Tags: python

I’m trying to change the ownership of a file or directory. When I move the function to a separate file it works perfectly and the ownership is changed. When I try to incorporate it into a large script it errors out with the following exception. I am running the script as sudo.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mount_py3.py", line 206, in <module>
    main()
  File "mount_py3.py", line 197, in main
    own_recursive(mount_point)
  File "mount_py3.py", line 112, in own_recursive
    os.chown(mtpt, uid, gid)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/srv/general'
```

A directory listing shows the following.

```sh
$ ll /srv
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 21 06:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Mar 22 14:01 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   39 Mar 14 01:44 general/
```

I actually call the os.chmod in two separate areas and I interactively get the name of the owner and group. Here is some of the relevant code.

```
        while True:
            inp_user = input("Enter the name of the default group:  ")

            try:
                uid = pwd.getpwnam(inp_user)[2]

            except KeyError:
                print("User name does not exist on this system. ")
                print("Exiting.  ")
                continue

            break

        while True:
            inp_group = input("Enter the default group name:  ")

            try:
                gid = grp.getgrnam(inp_group)[2]

            except KeyError:
                print("Group name does not exist on this system. ")
                print("Try again.  ")
                continue

            break

        os.setuid(0)
        os.chown(mtpt, uid, gid)
```

I expected some of the less relevant code but this is what is failing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute os.\* methods as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636136/how-to-execute-os-methods-as-root)

Comment: Samy - The commands would pass my accounts UID and GID.  Mostly for this I supporting DBA with their own sets of users and groups.  The os.chown function works great when I move it to its own python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discarding this post.  Opened a new one.